# Can we use AccountNumber field in Account object as an External ID?

Tags: integration, externalid

Can we use AccountNumber field in Account object as an External ID? Would upsert work with AccountNumber field? Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried THIS: in the dev console

```
Account a = New Account(Name='test', AccountNumber='1234');
upsert a accountNumber;
```

and got this message:

> Invalid field for upsert, must be an External Id custom or standard
>   indexed field: accountNumber

So I guess the answer is NO.